# Error reading csv numbers like "-1 000,00"

Tags: python, csv

I get errror when i try to read numbers like "-1 000,00".
Result is '-1\xa0000,00'.

How to fix my code to clear the error?

```
def read_csv(filename):
    list = []
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as local_file:
        fields = ['Account_group_name',
                  'Current_balance',
                  'Account_name',
                  'Transfer_account_name',
                  'Description',
                  'Partner_name',
                  'Category',
                  'Date',
                  'Time',
                  'Memo',
                  'Sum',
                  'Currency',
                  'Face_balance',
                  'Balance',
                  ]
        reader = csv.DictReader(local_file, fields, delimiter=';')
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            list.append(row)
    return list
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is utf-8 encoded?

Comment: Yes, I create a file in MoneyWiz program, and choose "UTF-8"

Comment: `\xa0` is a non-breakable space, so the csv import works correctly. What do you want to do with the numbers after you've read them that now fails?

Comment: Oh, I understand your idea. Thx. I think that the issue is closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an error, just a misunderstanding.